# What does 'font name' in the fontspec package refer to on a Mac

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mac

On a Mac using XeLaTeX and the `fontspec` package, what is meant by `font name`?

The Font Book application lists several possibilities:

- PostScript name
- Full name
- Family

I.e. which name should I type into the `\setmainfont [⟨font features⟩] {⟨font name⟩}` command?

For example, for the font named as Times (top unexpanded item) in Font Book, the following values exist:

```
 PostScript name: Times-Roman
 Full name:       Times Roman
 Family:          Times
```

[image: Viewing the Times font in Font Book]

Comment: Usually it should be what's in the "Family" field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XeTeX checks `Full` name first if no match and the name has a hyphen, it checks it as `Family-Style`, if no match checks `PostScript` name and finally if non of this matches, it will check `Family` name.

In most cases, you want to use `Family` name, so that XeTeX takes care of loading various font styles automatically (bold, italic etc.) unless you want only a specific style, then `Full` or `PostScript` names would be recommended (e.g. with `\newfontface`).

Comment: Thanks! Feels good to know a bit more about the inner workings.

Answer (score 2):

Both the *Postscript Name* and the *Full Name* should work with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

with `lualatex` I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont
  [UprightFont = * Roman,
      BoldFont = * Bold,
    ItalicFont = * Italic,
BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic,
]{Times}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}

Text $x+y=\sqrt{z}$ \textbf{Text} \textsc{Text}

\end{document}
```

If you do not have the XITS math then use another math font, like `Asana Math`

Comment: So to answer the OP's question, the *family* is a suitable value for the `\setmainfont` *font name*.